# .date("W") and <img> not working properly

Tags: php, html, image, date

I am (re)making a PHP script for an app i am developing.
It is supposed to get the number of the week, save it in a variable and apply this to a image source.
I had it working for quite a while but my hard drive crashed and i lost most of my code.
I am trying to recreate it but i seem to have stumbled upon a little problem.

This is what i normaly used.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            DKW Roosters    
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
<!--Begin dynamische week-->
        <?php
            echo "<h1>DKW Rooster week: " . date("W") . "</h1>";
        ?>
<!--Einde dynamische week-->
        <?php
            $w1 = "dkw_w" . date("W") . "_p1.jpg";
            echo '<img src="'.$w1.'" alt="Rooster DKW: Error" style="width:1200px;height:720px" >';
        ?>  
        <p></p>
        <?php
            $w1 = "dkw_w" . date("W") . "_p1.jpg";
            echo '<img src="'.$w1.'" alt="Rooster DKW: Error" style="width:1200px;height:720px" >';
        ?>
        <h2>Let op</h2>
        <p>Ga er van uit dat het rooster in de kantine het juiste rooster is!</p1>
        <p>Niet alle wijzigingen staan al op dit rooster!</p2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe this i how i had it before i lost it all.
But this is all i get when i try to view it:

[image]

I have tried all sorts of things to fix this, but i don't even have the slightest clue what i did last time to get it working....
It would be great if somebody were to explain to me how to fix this or show me what i did wrong.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not parsing the page as php.

This can be related to the page having an extension that is not.php or to a server side problem with your php engine.

Try to build a page info.php with this code and try to open it to see if it works:

```
<?php
    Phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Apparently it was a problem with my server, I have reset it and reinstalled PHP, it works fine now! I was so confused as to why my code didn't work...